# disable threading while executing in mingw

Tags: c++, multithreading, mingw

I use mingw under win7 to compile and launch the code.
There is no threading done by myself, the program is written plain straightforwardly.

However there is an error I can only relate to threading - the error appears in the same place of a cycle, but not at the same cycle count on different runs; if I put a simple output procedure just before the problem place, the error goes away!

If it is a threading problem, how can I make it running in one-thread (redesigning a thread-proof program is not really an option).

Thanks.

Comment: The error is in your code, it is not related to threading.

Comment: It sounds like *undefined behavior* is the culprit.

Comment: Debug it until you find out what the root cause is.  Only then, fix it.

Comment: Disabling threading is not the solution you are looking for. *hand wave*

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons for such behavior:

- Uninitialized variables
- Memory corruption
- Wrong assembly code
- Some time-specific information contributes to the result (`time()`, `rand()`)
- Undefined behavior